# How to view snort.log files

Tags: snort

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d8p5.png)

My snort.log file is completely empty and my snort.log.xxxxx files contain the characters @#...
I already know how to read the snort.log.xxx file but my snort.log file is empty and I don't know how to view it
Am using snort on ubuntu server
Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the log files that end with a 10 digit number (Epoch timestamp), you can add the .pcap extension to the log file itself than open it in packet viewer of your liking (for example Wireshark).

Answer (score 0):

You can view the log using `tshark` in linux command line.

For example: `tshark -r snort.log.xxxxx`